# How would I go about making an argument on my command-line like program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Essentially, I am trying to develop a command-line type program that has certain commands with their arguments. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to make a second argument for my commands. Example: `ping (second argument)`. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
inpt = input("$")
for i in range(0, len(inpt), 4):
    if inpt == "print":
        print(inpt.replace("print","")) #should print the second argument as a test
input()
```

Comment: http://click.pocoo.org/6/

Comment: Use `inpt.split()` to produce a list of words in the variable.  For example if the user typed `ping foo bar`, you would get `['ping', 'foo', 'bar']`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get values by using the input, if so just do what John Gordon is saying. But, you describe passing in arguments from the command line, like `./test.py arg1 arg2 arg3` etc. You might want to check out pythons optparse: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, to take arguments you would be looking at argv imported from sys.

example: test2.py
    from sys import argv

```
script, arg1, arg2 = argv

print(script)
print(arg1)
print(arg2)
```

Running the file

```
python3 test2.py my_arg1 my_arg2
test2.py
my_arg1
my_arg2
```

If you want to do the same thing but after asking for input from the user, then look at the `split()` method in the str class. You can use split to split on spaces, or any other character you'd like.